# What's the Azure equivalent of "Add application" in IIS?

Tags: azure, web-services

We use a app builder to create our applications, download them as .zip, and then just click "Add Application" on IIS, point to the application folder and it would be working.

Our applications require no server logic or database, they are self contained, the database is external and acessed via REST on javascript.

I can't seem to find the equivalent of the above procedure on Azure, it has options like Python/Node/Java/.NET but I'm not sure which of these fit our application needs.

How can I just easily upload a web app on Azure without any backend required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can drag/drop a zip file into the "kudu" console of an Azure webapp to upload the file.  Azure takes care of unzipping the file and putting the files in the web app.

To get to that portal, change your web app url to contain ".scm." and append /ZipDeploy to the end of the url:

https://yourwebapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/zipdeploy

Then drag/drop your file onto the web page.

From the main kudu page (remove zipdeploy from your url) you can upload entire directories of files if you need to.  I regularly deploy webapps this way and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest approaches is to make use of Azure App Services. This is Azure's Platform as a Service (Paas) offering that allows you to get a web site up fairly quickly whether that be a static site that is mostly client side logic or your more traditional apps such as asp.net\php\etc. You can deploy your app through various means from CI\CD, Github, FTP, etc.   You can find more details and a 5 minute quickstart at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/.

More recently Azure has offered the ability to host static web sites right in Azure's Blob storage.  It doesn't come with all the features of Azure App Services and does not have any server side execution but has the advantage of price and simplicity and when used in concert with some CDN networks it can be attractive for static client side only sites.  More details at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website